# What is the origin of the naming convention for the various branches in vibration-rotational spectroscopy?

Tags: history, spectroscopy, notation, raman-spectroscopy, mnemonic

In vibration-rotational spectroscopy, the different spectral lines are grouped into branches for different changes in the total angular momentum, i.e.
$$
\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
& \mathrm{O} & \mathrm{P} & \mathrm{Q} & \mathrm{R} & \mathrm{S} &\\\hline
\Delta J & -2 & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 
\end{array}$$
and so on. But why does it start with $\Delta J=0$ for Q?

Also: Does anyone know a mnemonic for it? I always forget with which letter it starts and if increasing $J$ means later or earlier letters.